# Checkbox as parameter in SSRS 2208R2 report

Tags: reporting-services, checkbox

How can I use checkbox as a parameter in SSRS report? There in no built in control for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must have a check box you can't use the built-in SSRS interface for collecting parameters. Microsoft Connect has an [issue regarding this](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/669971/allow-option-for-a-checkbox-for-boolean-parameters-in-ssrs).

You will need to make your own UI to collect the parameters and then eitehr redirect the user or return the report to them. Depending on your requirements, the simplest ways may be using [SSRS with URL Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153586.aspx) or using the [reportviewer webpart](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326214.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to implementing checkboxes on top of your report, you can use a multivalue text parameter. You can enter the default data manually and then it shows a combobox with the checkboxes you want. Each checkbox can be accessed using the same parameter name and an index. For example if the following condition is True then it means sombody has selected a checkbox that its value is 'value1':
InStr(Join(Parameters!p_myMultipleValueParameter.Value,","), "value1")>0

Note: In this case beware of text similarities. In same cases a string value of a checkbox may also be a substring of another value like 'no1' and 'no12'

Answer (score 0):

While you can cannot do native checkboxes, you can do Radio buttons via Datatype Boolean.